# Excel How return a text result from part of a number

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns. The first one will be a BSB number and the second will be the name of the bank. How can I create a formula or Macro where the first 2 or 3 digits in column 1 will determine the name of the bank in column 2. For example, If I enter 063215 in column 1, then column 2 would show 'Commonwealth' or if I enter 114879 it would return a result of 'St George', just from the first 2 or 3 digits. I'm pretty new to VBA and macro's in Excel, so please be kind. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your search box in a different cell on the form, the following formula should work. Such as the 3-digit number is in column A, the bank in column B, the search cell is C2, and the return cell is D2.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT($C$2,3),A:B,2),"")`

Comment: Hi Tytus, thanks for you reply, I found a formula that seems to work great - =IF(LEFT(Q6,2)="06","COMMONWEALTH",""). Unfortunately I'm not sure how to add IF statements for different banks.. for example, I tried the following

Comment: Hi Tytus, thanks for you reply, I found a formula that seems to work great - =IF(LEFT(Q6,2)="06","COMMONWEALTH",""). Unfortunately I'm not sure how to add IF statements for different banks.. for example, I tried the following...=IF(LEFT(Q6,2)="06","COMMONWEALTH","") OR =IF(LEFT(Q6,2)="01","ANZ","") but it didn't work. I've tried various other (similar) formula's but just displays '#VALUE!' instead of the bank name. So all I need is to be able to add multiple 'IF' statements so whenever I enter a BSB into a cell, another cell will display the corresponding bank name. Cheer's